# Error in upgrading pip on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, fedora

I am running the command on linux system as :

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

But I am getting the error message as :

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==6.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Where as, if I go and check the `pip --version`, I get the response as :

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Why do I need `'pip==6.1.1' distribution` and how do i get it ?

Comment: What does `sudo pip --version` show?

Comment: sudo pip --version gives the same error message : `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==6.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: So basically you have 2 `pip`s. One of your local user, another one that `root` (or sudo) sees. Easy "fix" would be `sudo easy_install pip`, which should reinstall your broken pip.

Comment: I am running a virtual python environment, when I try `sudo easy_install pip `, I get 
`sudo: easy_install: command not found`

Comment: Oh, wait. Disregard that. I just read that you're running a virtualenv.. Then you don't need sudo at all, it means your current venv pip is OK.

Comment: When I run `yum install python-setuptools` , I get 
`Package python26-setuptools-12.2-1.32.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

And again if I try `easy_install`, it gives the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132115/discussion-between-favoretti-and-sarang).

Comment: Not related to programming. Try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) Or [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On upgrading `pip` on thesystem, as the root user, you actually overwrite your system PIP program, and are subject to severe problem when further installing Python packages for your Linux system (with yum/dnf).

The correct way to work with this is to create a virtualenv as a user, and on that virtualenv you upgrade PIP. Isolated from the system Python installation.  Anything remotely serious you will want to do with Python on this machine should be running at least Python 2.7 anyway - or 3.6 if it is Python 3 compatible. (Your system Python is 2.6  and you have a Python2. on /usr/local which might conflict, exactly depending on the order of PATH as you found out).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in case, pip should be upgraded by using `sudo pip install --upgrade pip.`

But since I am getting the error as : `sudo: easy_install: command not found`

I need to set environment variable path as below :

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Once done, the upgrade command works normally.